# sudo yum install gitlab-ce "Nothing to Do" when trying to Upgrade to latest version of gitlab

Tags: centos, upgrade, gitlab, yum, gitlab-omnibus

I am trying to update to the latest version of gitlab on my CentOS server. I am currently running Omnibus version 8.3.2, which has a security issue. I am using the instructions from the [update](https://about.gitlab.com/update/) page:

sudo yum install gitlab-ce

Whenever I run this command I get a "Nothing to Do" from the Yum command.

```
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security, ulninfo
Setting up Install Process
Nothing to do
```

I have also tried a manual update with a .rpm file and I get conflict errors because it isn't removing the older version. What am I missing in order to upgrade my version? I am new to this so I apologize if I am over complicating things. I really don't want to uninstall and re-install the latest version.

Thanks in advace

Comment: What does `rpm -q gitlab-ce` return? What RPM did you try manually? With what command exactly? (I'm betting `rpm -ivh $package`, right?) What version of CentOS is this? `ulninfo` is an Oracle thing isn't it? Is this CentOS or Oracle? What does `yum -d 6 repolist` output for the configured repositories?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7. But using CentOS instructions. rpm -q gitlab-ce returns: gitlab-ce-8.3.2-ce.0.el6.x86_64 . I tried rpm -i $package. Using gitlab-ce-8.7.1-ce.1.el7.x86_64.rpm.

Comment: That's an `el7` package so not the right package for `el6` anyway. And yes, you used `-i`. Don't do that. Use `-U` for "upgrade". `-i` for "install" is almost **never** the flag you want. What about the output from `repolist`?

Comment: That was it, I got it to work with a el6 package and the -U. Thank you so much!

Comment: That's not "it". The repo still isn't working and it probably should be but it did let you work around that problem at least.